# print a dictionary in 2 different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, formatting

I have a dictionary in this format:

```
my_dict = {'a':{'x':10}, 'b':{'z':7}, 'w':{'y':4}, 'y':{'q':1}, 'q':{'m':15}, 't':{'z':34}, 's':{'y':44}}
```

Each string maps to a dictionary of a `{string:value}`. I want to print the first string, and the string in the dictionary.
I want it in 2 columns, like this:

```
a:x | b:z
w:y | y:q
q:m | t:z
s:y |
```

How can I do this?

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print('{}:{}'.format(key, value.key?))
```

Comment: Why does 'a' map to 'b', and 'w' to 'u', but 'q' maps to 'm'? Then 't' continues the previous pattern, mapping to 's'... The logic seems to be off, here.

Comment: what exactly is `{'x',10}`...a list or tuple?

Comment: your dictionary contains sets as values. But there is no deterministic first item of a set (because they are by design _unordered_). Do you mean the string? Could you clarify?

Comment: oops! I meant `:` not commas

Comment: Edited to clarify

Comment: @not_a_robot sorry, I messed up my question. I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. It doesn't print out *exactly* what you want, since built-in `dict`s are hashed and thus unordered. The `chunk` function below splits a list evenly into `n`-sized chunks. So you'll want to iterate over your dictionary with `my_dict.items()` and create pairs out of each element in `my_dict.items()`.

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

pairs = chunks(list(my_dict.items()), 2)
```

After you have the pairs set up, all you have to do is index the elements in `pairs` appropriately. The `list(x[0][1].keys())[0]` syntax is just grabbing the key from the nested dictionary, and assumes your nested dictionaries only contain one key.

```
for x in pairs:
    if len(x) > 1:
        print("{}: {} | {}: {}".format(x[0][0], list(x[0][1].keys())[0], x[1][0], list(x[1][1].keys())[0]))
    else:
        print("{}: {}".format(x[0][0], list(x[0][1].keys())[0]))
```

Which prints this:

```
b: z | s: y
w: y | y: q
q: m | t: z
a: x
```

Edit: Per the comment below, yes there is a way to print it alphabetically. Just use `sorted` on the list returned by `list(my_dict.items())` to sort by the first element in each tuple.

```
res = sorted(list(my_dict.items()), key = lambda x: x[0])

# new chunks based on sorted list
pairs = chunks(res, 2)
```

`pairs` looks like this (it's actually a generator, but under the hood it's this):

```
[[('a', {'x': 10}), ('b', {'z': 7})], [('q', {'m': 15}), ('s', {'y': 44})], [('t', {'z': 34}), ('w', {'y': 4})], [('y', {'q': 1})]]
```

From there, you can use the same `for` loop from above...

Comment: Is there any way to get it alphabetically?